# Ec2 instance opened port not connecting from certain regions

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

I have installed SQL Server in an AWS instance (Ubuntu) and it is working perfectly but found that it is not able to connect to the database from certain IPs (from that region not working for any ISPs). My port 1433 is open and I am able to access it from my system. Here is my security group configuration: [image]
But in my friends system which is in a different network it is not connecting though I can access port 80 from that system. I telnet that port (1433) and it is throwing "could not connect host". I tried tracetcp and after 9 hops the requests are timed out. I used VPN in that system and it got connected.

Not able to determine what could be the issue. Not a network pro and any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing (with "my system" and "my friends system"). Are you saying that you are attempting to connect to an SQL Server running on an Amazon EC2 instance, and it works from your computer (on the Internet) but not from another computer (that is on the Internet)? Is that "other computer" connected to the same office network, or is it located somewhere else? I'm asking that because it would impact whether it appears to be coming from a different IP address.

Comment: It is possible that the issue is related to your Security Group.  Please Edit your question to show us the configuration of the **Security Group** attached to the Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have edited my question and added my security group screenshot. My friends computer is also connected to net and is in a different region. In fact  the port 80 is working fine when doing telnet from that system but port 1433 is not working.

Comment: The security groups have both ports open to the entire Internet. Therefore, if one person can connect from the Internet but another person cannot connect from the Internet, the problem lies with something to do with the person who can't connect. It is either being caused by their computer or their network connection. The problem would not be on AWS. If one of you used a VPN and one of you didn't, then that might provide a clue as to why it is different for one of you!

Comment: Yes ideally it should work. The strange thing is that it is not working for any internet service provider in that area.